Estimating integrals and measures over Hilbert space using finite dimensional projections
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Let $P_n$ be the projection onto the $n$-dimensional subspace of $H$:
$$P_n x = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i, \quad x \in H.$$
Is it possible to compute measures and integrals over $H$ using a limit of the operators $P_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? That is, if $\mu$ is a probability measure over $H$ and $A$ is a measurable set in $H$, then could we estimate $\mu(A)$ using the $P_n$? If so, how is this done?
Similarly, suppose we have either the Bochner integral
$$\int_H x d\mu(x) \tag{1}$$
or equivalently the scalar-valued integral
$$\int_H \langle x, h\rangle d\mu(x)$$
is it possible to compute these integrals as measures over finite dimensional subspaces of $H$ using the projections? For example, I have in mind something like:
$$\int_H \lim_{n \rightarrow} P_n x d\mu(x)$$
but there are a number of issues with this approach. First, to compute (1) using the above integral one would have to interchange the integral and the limit but this is nontrivial. Second, how do these projections affect the infinite dimensional measure $d\mu$? Do they become something like a measure over $P_nH$, and if so, how are these defined?

Did you mean your orthonormal basis as indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$? Otherwise $P_n$ does not converge to $1$.

Interchanging limits and integrals in calculating (1) is fine, as long as all integrals involved are well-defined. The limit at least works weakly, which can be directly verified by taking the inner product with a fixed $h \in H$. It should also work in norm if $\mu$ is compactly supported.

Not sure what you meant by estimating $\mu(A)$ using $P_n$. Projections don't send measurable sets to measurable sets, so considering $P_nA$ doesn't make sense. $A$ could also be disjoint from $P_nH$ for all $n$, so considering $A \cap P_nH$ won't work either.

Inducing a measure on $P_n$ is easy enough though though. $P_n$ is a Borel map from $H$ to $P_nH$, so you can just talk about the induced measure on $P_nH$.

@DavidGao Thank you very much for your comments and for catching that typo, I've corrected my post. Could you elaborate on why the integral works weakly or why it works in norm if $\mu$ is compactly supported? For all this to work I assume we would need $u$ to be integrable from the outset? That is, we can't approximate/estimate the value of $\int u d\mu(u)$ using projections if $u$ is not integrable?

If $u$ is not integrable, the integral $\int u , d\mu$ is not well-defined in the first place. I’m not sure what you even meant to estimate the value of the integral in this case.

$$\langle \int P_nx , d\mu(x), h \rangle = \int \langle P_nx, h \rangle , d\mu(x) = \int \langle x, P_nh \rangle , d\mu(x) = \langle \int x , d\mu(x), P_nh \rangle \to \langle \int x , d\mu(x), h \rangle$$for all $h$, so $\int P_nx , d\mu(x) \to \int x , d\mu(x)$ weakly.

For the compactly supported case, this follows from the observation that, whenever $A \subset H$ is compact, $\sup_{x \in A} |x - P_nx| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

@DavidGao Sorry for asking more follow up questions, but for a Bochner integral what justifies exchanging the integral and the inner product, and the fact that $\langle P_n x, h \rangle = \langle x, P_nh \rangle$? What I meant by estimating the integral is if $u$ may not be integrable, is it still always true that $P_n u$ is integrable?

Bochner integral can be interchanged with any bounded linear operator. Just write down the definition of Bochner integral using simple functions and the result is immediate. $\langle P_nx, h \rangle = \langle x, P_nh \rangle$ is just using $P_n$ being self-adjoint.

No, of course not. $u$ could have range in some $P_nH$ (or $\mu$ could be supported in some $P_nH$) and it could still be non-integrable.

(I suppose I was not thinking clearly when I thought you need compact support to get strong limit. That was not necessary. You directly have$$\int P_nx , d\mu = P_n\int x, d\mu \to \int x , d\mu$$in norm by interchanging the Bochner integral and the bounded operator $P_n$.)

@DavidGao Thank you for all your help! If you would like to write this all all up as an answer I will accept it.

Interchanging the limit and the integral is fine in this case. Indeed, using the definition of Bochner integrals, by approximating with simple functions, one easily observes that Bochner integrals can be interchanged with the application of bounded linear operators, so in particular,
$$\int P_nx \, d\mu(x) = P_n\int x \, d\mu(x) \to \int x \, d\mu(x)$$
in norm.
This, of course, assumes $x$ is integrable w.r.t. $\mu$ - since we’re in a separable space, this is just the same as saying the Lebesgue integral $\int \|x\| \, d\mu(x) < \infty$. Note that this automatically implies $P_nx$ is integrable for all $n$. Also note that when $x$ is not integrable, the integral $\int x \, d\mu(x)$ does not make sense, and $P_nx$ could be non-integrable as well - $\mu$ could be supported on $P_nH$ for some $n$ and still $x$ could be non-integrable. (Even in dimension $1$, not all probability distributions have a well-defined finite mean.)

Projections don’t send measurable sets to measurable sets in general, so $P_nA$ isn’t necessarily measurable, and thus it’s not possible to consider $\mu(P_nA)$. A non-null set $A$ could also be disjoint from $P_nH$ for all $n$, so considering $A \cap P_nH$ won’t help in approximating $\mu(A)$. As such, there seems to be no way of approximating $\mu(A)$ using the projections $P_n$.
Though, inducing measures on $P_nH$ is easy: $P_n$ is a continuous and thus Borel map from $H$ to $P_nH$, so the pushforward probability measure $P_n^\ast \mu$ makes sense.

Thank you again! As a last question, do you have any textbooks you can suggest for learning more about Bochner integrals and measures over infinite dimensional spaces?

@CBBAM I’m not an expert in the field, but you can try Analysis in Banach Spaces by Hytönen, van Neerven, Veraar, and Weis. That’s where I learned what I know about Bochner integrals, at least.
